# Should there be a "the" before "consideration" in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

> It should be not excluded from **consideration** that by choosing Katha as their candidate, the incumbent party revealed its goal to expand influence in the northern districts.

Answer (score 0):

No. "The" would have no useful meaning in this context.

Answer (score 0):

There are two senses of consideration that should be considered here; [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consideration) classifies them with regard to countness† and has good examples::

> (B1) **consideration** [noun] [non-count]: the act of thinking about
> something carefully:
>
> - *After some consideration, we've decided to sell the house*.
> - careful consideration: *The whole matter needs (to be given) careful consideration*.
> - *As I was just saying, I think the proposal needs further consideration*.
> - *Three sites are presently under consideration for the new hotel*.
> - *I've put my proposition to the company director for his consideration*.
> - *The proposals that you have put forward deserve serious consideration*.
>
> (B2) **consideration** [noun][count and non-count usages]: a
> particular subject or fact that needs to be thought about when judging
> something:
>
> - *Comfort/Safety is an important consideration*.
> - [*Comfort and safety are [two] important considerations.*]

(There are also the considerateness and remuneration senses.)

Note that the prepositional complement examples all take the non-count (B1) usage and no definite article. Even those non-count examples taking a determiner (some, his) do not allow the definite article.

There is a possible pairing with the definite article, though:

> - [This was put forward]  for the consideration of the Intergovernmental  Negotiating Body at its fourth meeting. [[World Health Organisation](https://apps.who.int/gb/inb/pdf_files/inb4/A_INB4_3-en.pdf)]

but note here that there is an of-phrase after the word.

In the given sentence in the question, it is incorrect to add a definite article.

- *It should be not excluded from consideration that ...*

=

- *It should be borne in mind that* ...

and no one would suggest a definite article ('in the mind') here.

............

†'Countness' is used in the linguistic sense in for example ['Mass/countness and gender in Asturian'; Michele Loporcaro; Oxford Academic](https://academic.oup.com/book/35951/chapter-abstract/310490224?redirectedFrom=fulltext).

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation, Edwin! A grammar checker that suggested adding "the" had me confused.